# Sending a custom ArrayList through an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I'm having a problem when working with custom ArrayLists and trying to move them between activities. First I've declared a custom ArrayList in my first activity:

```
private ArrayList<String[]> dataArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Where each element of the ArrayList is an array of String elements.

Next, I put it into an intent with putExtra():

```
Intent int1 = new Intent(this, ManualModeActivity.class);
int1.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, dataArray);
```

Then, when I try to recover the ArrayList in my second Activity, I find that there's only a getStringArrayListExtra() method for `ArrayList<String>` elements, so it doesn't work with `ArrayList<String[]>`. I've been searching about this and all I find are examples with custom objects where the solution is to implement a Parcelable or Serialize interface on them. How could I do this with a "default" object like String[]? (Or maybe am I missing something about how interfaces works since I'm still a newbie in java?)

Comment: yes it's right you use `Parcelable` or `Serialize` interface for custom arraylist

Comment: use `getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)` to get the data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for sending the data from the first activity is correct.

For receiving data in the second activity use `intent`'s `getSerializableExtra()` method, something like:

```
ArrayList<String[]> data = (ArrayList<String[]>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```